# Check 4 chars with regex Ruby console input

Tags: ruby, regex, console

I have 4 chars, first one is letter 'L' for example, the other two are numbers and the last one is letter again, all of them are separated by one space. User is entering them in the Ruby console. I need to check that they are separated by one space and don't have other weird characters and that there is nothing after the last letter.

So if a user enters for example gets.chomp = 'L 5 7 A', I need to check that everything is ok and separated by only one space and return input[1], input[2], input[3]. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: _I have 3 chars, first one is [...] the other two are [...] and the last one is [...]_ I count 4 chars.

Comment: @user1993565 A *very* easy task with regex. Where are you stuck?

Comment: @ThomasWilmotte Yes, you do. It was a typo and not the point of the question.

Comment: @biffen I am trying with regex but can't do much. How do I say that all of them must be separated by a space?

Comment: \s checks for one space

Comment: @user1993565 By putting spaces in the regex. You'll have to show us what you've tried if we are to help you.

Comment: @davidhu2000 *No*, `\s` checks for one *whitespace character*.

Comment: I tried this but not working: 'L 2 3 A' =~ /^L\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+([A-Z])\s+$/           And how can I return second, third and fourth value after I check it?

Comment: is input[1] = L in your example?

Comment: @user1993565 I think you want something more like `/^(L) (\d) (\d) ([A-Z])$/`. Not sure why you have all those pluses in there, nor why you need to capture `L`.

Comment: Thanks. When I try this, it return 0 (zero). Not sure what that means. What if there is more than one space between them? When I do input[1] I get " " (space) but I want input[1] to be 2 for example. Is that possible?

Comment: I've edited my answer, pretty sure it's what you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
puts "Enter string"
input = gets.chomp
r = /^(L)\s(\d)\s(\d)\s([A-Z])$/                                        
matches = input.match r

puts matches ? "inputs: #{$1}, #{$2}, #{$3}, #{$4}" : "input-format incorrect"
```

Here `$1` is the first capture, similarly for `$2`, `$3` etc. If you want to store the result in an array you can use:

```
matches = input.match(r).to_a
```

then the first element is the entire match, followed by each capture.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
/^\w\s(\d)\s(\d)\s(\w)$/
```

[Rubular](http://rubular.com) is a good sandbox site for experimenting with and debugging regexes.